# Reputation for comment votes

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, comments

When posting my questions, I have found that often someone knows the important question to ask. This is at the core of fundamental research and difficult when you are out of your knowledge base to even devise the correct question which would solve the originating concern. It's frequently most important to ask the question. I urge consideration of the author being able to grade or show a value to the question other than just in the response to the question. Also urging here that it go to increase the value of the reputation of the person asking the followup question as it both mentors and helps the original author learn.

Comment: Good questions receive upvotes, and each upvote provides five reputation points to the OP. Are you asking for something beyond that?

Comment: yes, good counter questions by people seeing the original question are the focus of my question

Comment: If you mean requests for clarification via comments, you can upvote them as well. This does not provide a reputation increase, but it lets others know that you found the comment to be helpful.

Comment: Will you clarify whether you are talking about questions left _via comments_ or something else?

Comment: yes questions via comments, I think mine is just not knowing how to upvote a comment... i can research this (for example your comment which starts "If you mean...", I found that at the core of what I needed. So if there was a way to raise it, that would be of help.

Comment: To upvote a comment, hover over it with your mouse. Just to the left of the comment, two icons will appear: a light gray up arrow and flag. Click the up arrow to upvote the comment.

Comment: Are there any addons required? I am using centos 6.3/firefox 17.0.5 and there are no arrows and no flag. That explains some of the confusion. The comment does grey slightly, but that is all. I also do not see this feature in Unbuntu with Firefox 21.0. Third checked Windows 7 using firefox, no arrows or flag, lasttly windows 7 with Internet Explorer - only grey no arrows or flag. Maybe I am missing something indicating the feature with my login. ty for responding -

Comment: Please stop repeatedly changing the question. I am going to revert it to the original question. If you have a new question, click the "Ask Question" button in the top right corner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) says that comments on SE sites are meant to be temporary:

> Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer.

They can be used to ask for clarification or as a place for necessary discussion about a question.

However, comments are not permanent. All relevant information should eventually be moved to a question or answer, since comments may be deleted at any time for a variety of reasons.

If we introduce a system of rewards for good comments, we would also have to rething the permanence of comments. In my opinion, the presence of useful information in comments
often means that a question or answer is less than complete. I prefer to keep the current system and ensure that we are editing the useful information into the questions and answers.

You can upvote helpful comments. This does not provide a reputation increase, but it lets others know that you found the comment to be helpful

Comment: Where are you getting that this proposal has anything to do with comments?

Comment: It is an assumption, but is based on the following: "_When posting my questions, I have found that often someone knows the important question to ask._" The OP is asking a question, so the "important question to ask" must be a response of some sort. Additionally, the OP said in a comment "_good counter questions by people seeing the original question_". Since the OP did not comment on the value of the 5-point rep for voting up questions, I assume he/she is referring to counter-questions left via comments.

Comment: @Cody Additional clarification was added, so we now know that comments were the intended topic of discussion.

Comment: Perhaps I need to research this more, I may be using non-standard nomenclature for parts and peices of the system which cause confusion. Thx,

Comment: OK, when I hover over the comments I am not seeing a way to "upvote helpful comments". So I suppose there may be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

No. I dont think we need this. Other than the fact that the current system works fine, there is also the significant chance of gaming rep for clarifying comments.

Lets take users A, B to be sockpuppets of C, a Stack Overflow evil overlord.

- A posts question.
- C posts comment.
- A and B upvote C's comment. Free rep to C.
- C posts another comment.
- A and B upvote C's comment. Free rep to C.
- Repeat.

Comment: Are you saying that comments give reputation?

Comment: @brasofilo No, he's just making the assumption that that's what the OP wants.

Comment: @michaelb958, thx, I'm not being able to parse the Q, this A just added to my confusion.

Comment: @brasofilo I don't think **anybody** can parse this Q.

Comment: Actually, even I wasnt able to parse the question. I am just answering this based on [this comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/165786/george-cummins) as the OP expressed agreement with it (suggesting that that was the intention of the question).

Comment: sorry for the confusion. AND I think that is true about the gaming. I was thinking about it and realized someone may know the answer and just try to lead you on with relevent questions... =0) um... not good if they do that.

Comment: brasofilo - yes, you got it. It was what was requested.